# Infinite length Composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a group (possibly infinite). Suppose $G$ has a composition series. I could show that any other composition series has the same length. But I cannot prove the following.

Let $G \triangleright G_2 \triangleright G_3 \triangleright \cdots$ be a series of normal groups (may or may not assume the successive quotients are simple). I want to show that this series should terminate, i.e., there is $N$ such that $G_i=G_N$ for any $i >N$.

Comment: Clearly the group has to be infinite for the problem not to be boringly trivial, so your first parentheses is odd.

Comment: @DonAntonio I just wanted people not to get a wrong idea.

Comment: This is the same question as  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844155

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think the question is the same. I am assuming $G$ has at least one composition series.

Comment: It is the identical questions worded differently.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right. But how do you prove the claim?

Answer (score -2):

This is not true, take $G=Z^N$ and $G_i$ the subgroup such that $x\in G_i$ if its first $i$ components are zero.

Comment: I am assuming $G$ has a composition series. Does your example have a composition series?

Comment: Yes, $G_{i+1}$ is normal in $G_i$

Comment: By a composition series, I mean a finite length series of normal groups whose successive quotients are simple.

Comment: If the serie is finite it terminates, ...you precised that you don't request to the quotients to be simple.

Comment: @TsemoAristide An abelian group has a (finite, by definition) composition series iff it is finite.

Comment: But op consider the case of infinite groups in his question

Comment: @Tsemo The OP gives a group for which we assume it has a composition series. As commented, for the problem to be non-trivial one may assume the group is infinite, but with comp. series (and thus it is non-abelian). Then, if it has a normal series as shown...etc.